# How to repeat an action of finding and clicking an element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some piece of code that visits a specific page by searching through the pagination element and clicking on a specific page. Then the code clicks on the view buttons one by one. After clicking a single view button, it copies the url on the next page and clicks close button and repeats the same process.

The challenge I am having is I need to visit the specified page each time - just before clicking any view button. The reason is even if I am on say, page 10 and click to copy the link, then click the close button, the page redirects me back to the default page i.e page 1. That is the default behaviour of the page that I am working on. So to avoid that, I have to return to the specific page (in my code example, page 2) each time I want to click the view button so that the code fetches the content on page 2 and not page 1. The first time the code works well and fetches the first row of page two but the subsequent rows are for page one because the default page behaviour takes over. This is what I want to avoid.

I added the code just before the code clicks on the viewButton.click(); but it does not work and stops clicking on the next view buttons completely. I am stuck hope someone could take a look.

What I have so far (*Added many comments to help quickly understand what's happening):

```
// Get a reference to the pagination container
const pagination = document.querySelector('.e-pager');

// Function to click on the next page button and check for the target element
function clickAndCheck() {
  // Get a reference to the next page button
  const nextButton = pagination.querySelector('.e-next.e-icons.e-icon-next.e-nextpage.e-pager-default');
  // Click on the next page button
  nextButton.click();
  // Check if the target element is now visible
  const targetElement = pagination.querySelector('a[index="2"]');
  if (targetElement !== null) {
    // Click on the target element
    targetElement.click();

    // Wait for 5 seconds before running the second code
    setTimeout(runSecondCode, 5000);
  } else {
    // If target element is not yet visible, repeat the process after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(clickAndCheck, 2000);
  }
}

// Start the process by clicking on the next page button
clickAndCheck();

// Function to process rows
function processRows() {
  var currentRowIndex = 0;

  function processNextRow() {
    // Find the "View" button element for the current row
    var viewButton = document.querySelector(`tr.e-row[aria-rowindex="${currentRowIndex}"] b[style="color: blue; cursor: pointer;"]`);

    // If there is no next row, show alert and exit the function
    if (!viewButton) {
      alert("No More Tenders");
      return;
    }

    // Get a reference to the next page button
  const nextButton = pagination.querySelector('.e-next.e-icons.e-icon-next.e-nextpage.e-pager-default');
  // Click on the next page button
  nextButton.click();
  // Check if the target element is now visible
  const targetElement = pagination.querySelector('a[index="2"]');
  if (targetElement !== null) {
    // Click on the target element
    targetElement.click();

    // Wait for 5 seconds before running the second code
    setTimeout(runSecondCode, 5000);
  } else {
    // If target element is not yet visible, repeat the process after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(clickAndCheck, 2000);
  }

    // Simulate a click on the "View" button for the current row
    viewButton.click();

    // Wait for 10 seconds before extracting the link and clicking the "Close" button
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Find the link element
      var linkElement = document.querySelector('td[colspan="3"] a[href^="https://tenders.go.ke/OneTender/"]');

      // Extract the link from the href attribute
      var link = linkElement ? linkElement.getAttribute("href") : null;

      // Simulate a click on the "Close" button
      var closeButton = document.querySelector('button.btn.btn-warning.p-2[type="button"][style*="background-color: rgb(245, 156, 26)"]');
      closeButton.click();

      // Do something with the link
      console.log(link);

      // Increment the row index for the next loop
      currentRowIndex++;

      // Process the next row after 1 second
      setTimeout(processNextRow, 5000);

    }, 500);
  }

  // Start processing the rows
  processNextRow();
}

// Function to run the second code
function runSecondCode() {
  processRows();
}
```

Comment: How do you include this code on the page?

Comment: I am executing the code as a snippet inside Dev Console > Sources.

Comment: Then each time that navigation occurs the code is no longer in the memory, so you have to execute it again to be able to do anything.

Comment: It executes well in the first instance. I added the code that finds and clicks on the pagination right before the viewButton.click() function so that each time it tries to click the button, it first encounters a code it's supposed to execute which is click the target element. But that is not what the code is doing. Sorry if I did not understand.

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to say, but have a hunch that `event.preventDefault()` inside the click handler (and maybe `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`) can be interesting for you.